# Unable to import a function from outside the current working directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I am currently having difficulties import some functions which are located in a python file which is in the parent directory of the working directory of the main flask application script. Here's how the structure looks like

```
project_folder
- public
--app.py
-scripts.py
```

here's a replica code for `app.py`:

```
def some_function():
    from scripts import func_one, func_two
    func_one()
    func_two()
    print('done')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_function()
```

`scripts.py` contain the function as such:

```
def func_one():
    print('function one successfully imported')


def func_two():
    print('function two successfully imported')
```

What is the pythonic way of importing those functions in my `app.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precede it with a dot so that it searches the current directory (project_folder) instead of your python path:

```
from .scripts import func_one, func_two
```

The details of relative imports are described in [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

Edit: I assumed you were working with a package. Consider adding an `__init__.py` file.

Anyways, you can import anything in python by altering the system path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/directory")
from x import y
```

Comment: I tried that and I got: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.scripts'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: Is there an \_\_init__.py? If so, what's the \_\_name__?

Comment: There's no __init__.py anywhere as per structure that I have shown to you.

Comment: Where should the init file be placed?

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
import importlib.util

def loadbasic():
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("basic", os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], 'basic.py'))
    basic = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(basic)
    return basic #returns a module
```

2. Or create an empty file `__init__.py` in the directory.

And

3. do not pollute your path with appends.

Comment: Which of the folders should the init file be placed in?

Comment: better to all your paths. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for